# Implement tab view with sorting and pagination in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii, yii-components, yii-events

Am trying to bring a tab view with list , sorting and pagination in Yii. I have 2 tables named service_request and favourites where the datas come from. In that page I need to display the service request and favourites added date and some other fields. I tried to implement it with join , but it is not successfully listing the datas from service request. In my controller action I had added

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'favourite_notes,s.service_request_id';
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN service_request s  ON  service_request_id = 1';
$criteria->condition = 'favourite_type = 1';
    $data=new CActiveDataProvider('ProviderFavourite',array('criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>1)
                ));
            $this->renderPartial('viewtest', array(
                'ModelInstance' => ProviderFavourite::model()->findAll($criteria),
                'dataProvider'=>$data,
            ));
```

In viewtest I had provided,

```
         $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,'itemView'=>'view',     
             'id'=>'request-list',
'template' => '  {items}{pager}',
));
```

In view page, I had fetched the data

```
   echo $data->service_request;
    echo $data->favourite_notes;
```

All your suggestions are welcome..

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own function for sorting using CDBCriteria

at model side you can orderby and orderById pass through get or post

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias='b';
$criteria->order='b.'.$orderById.' '.$orderBy.',b.type asc,b.smallimage desc';
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($this->tableName(), array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>$limit,
        ),
    ));
```

Now at view side you can do like here Web pager is pagination class and extrapara is array of parameter those need for pagination

```
            $this->widget('application.extensions.WebPager',
            array(
            'cssFile'=>false,
            'pages' => $pagination,
            'extraPara'=>$extraPara,
            'id'=>'link_pager'
            ));
```